# How to start a process and wait for its child process to finish

Tags: c, windows

Is there a way to start a process, and wait for its child process to finish? My problem is the following. I have a setup.exe. If i start it, it runs for 4-5 secs and starts 1 or 2 new processes, and the setup.exe closes.

If i start setup.exe with createprocess and with WaitForSingleObject, then it will wait only then until the setup.exed closes.

Is there a way, to wait until the new processes, started by setup.exe finishes too?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683902/waiting-for-grandchild-processes-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

Maby you can create a Mutex on startup and lock it. Then, make base process wait for it using WaitForSingleObject api. The Mutex is automatically destroyed when its owner process is terminated.

Alternatively you can create a tmp File in the child process which you terminate when the process is finished, your setup.exe can check if the frim exists to know if the process is still running.

Comment: Mutex objects are only destroyed once the last handle is closed.  They are signaled when the owner thread terminates, but that still doesn't help with the grandchild processes.