# Inno Setup CreateProcess Winapi call error: Could not convert into OleStr

Tags: inno-setup, pascal, createprocess

I wrote a small installer and I want to do the things written here: [Waiting for grandchild processes in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683902/waiting-for-grandchild-processes-in-windows)
(I want to wait until another uninstaller is finished)

I defined the necessary types, and std calls.

Here is my code:

```
procedure UninstallPreviousVersion;
  var
    UninstallString: String;
    ErrorCode: Integer;

    UninstallJob : THandle;
    UninstallStartUpInfo : LPSTARTUPINFO;
    UninstallProcessInfo : LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;

begin

  UninstallJob := CreateJobObject( '' , '' );

  CreateProcess(
    '',
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{2FEAF140-139A-11D5-8925-0050DAE02BFF}\Setup.exe',
    null, 
    null,
    false,
    4,  //CREATE_SUSPENDED 0x00000004
    null, 
    null,
    UninstallStartUpInfo,
    UninstallProcessInfo
  );

  AssignProcessToJobObject( UninstallJob , UninstallProcessInfo.hProcess );
  ResumeThread( UninstallProcessInfo.hThread );
  WaitForSingleObject( UninstallJob , $FFFFFFFF );

  MsgBox('Uninstall returned! Wohohohooo yeah!', mbInformation, MB_OK);

end;
```

It compiles, and according to the debugger it fails during the CreateProcess function. When I run the setup the following error comes up: 
    Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (OleStr).

The defined types:

```
type
  LPSTARTUPINFO = record
  cb : DWORD;
  lpReserved : String; 
  lpDesktop : String;  
  lpTitle : String;                                                                    
  dwX:DWORD;
  dwY:DWORD;
  dwXSize:DWORD;
  dwYSize:DWORD;
  dwXCountChars : DWORD;
  dwYCountChars : DWORD;
  dwFillAttribute : DWORD;
  dwFlags : DWORD;
  wShowWindow : WORD;
  cbReserved2 : WORD;
  lpReserved2 : BYTE;
  hStdInput : Thandle;
  hStdOutput : Thandle;
  hStdError : Thandle;
end;

type
  LPPROCESS_INFORMATION  = record
  hProcess:THandle;
  hThread:THandle;
  dwProcessId:DWORD;
  dwThreadId:DWORD;
end;
```

I can upload more types if necessary.

**EDIT:**

This version compiles and launches the desired .exe.
Compiler: Inno Setup 5.5
The types are not defined, you have to define it yourself! Look up them on the windows dev site. (there are two examples above).

```
procedure UninstallPreviousVersion;
  var
    UninstallString: String;
    ErrorCode: Integer;

    UninstallJob : THandle;
    UninstallStartUpInfo : LPSTARTUPINFO;
    UninstallProcessInfo : LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;

    Info : LPVOID;
    procAtt : LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
    threadAtt : LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
begin

  UninstallStartUpInfo.lpReserved := '';
  UninstallStartUpInfo.lpDesktop := '';
  UninstallStartUpInfo.lpTitle := '';
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwX := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwY := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwXSize := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwYSize := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwXCountChars := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwYCountChars := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwFillAttribute := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.dwFlags := ( $00000001 ) or ( $00000200 );    //STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
  UninstallStartUpInfo.wShowWindow := SW_SHOW;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.cbReserved2 := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.lpReserved2 := 0;
  UninstallStartUpInfo.cb := sizeof(UninstallStartUpInfo);

  UninstallJob := CreateJobObject( '' , '' );

  CreateProcess(
    'C:\Program Files (x86)\\InstallShield Installation Information\{2FEAF140-139A-11D5-8925-0050DAE02BFF}\Setup.exe',
    'UNINSTALL',
    procAtt, 
    threadAtt,
    false,
    4,  //CREATE_SUSPENDED 0x00000004
    Info, 
    '',
    UninstallStartUpInfo,
    UninstallProcessInfo
  );

  AssignProcessToJobObject( UninstallJob , UninstallProcessInfo.hProcess );
  ResumeThread( UninstallProcessInfo.hThread );
  WaitForSingleObject( UninstallJob , $FFFFFFFF );  

end;
```

Comment: The startup info is an input parameter. You don't populate it at all.

Comment: You also did not perform any error checking at all.

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems in your code.

First, Pascal (including Inno Setup's Pascal Script) does not use `NULL` except when referring to `Variant` types. Convert the use of `null` to `nil` in the call to `CreateProcess`, to start.

```
CreateProcess(
  '',
  'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{2FEAF140-139A-11D5-8925-0050DAE02BFF}\Setup.exe',
  nil, 
  nil,
  false,
  4,  //CREATE_SUSPENDED 0x00000004
  nil, 
  nil,
  UninstallStartUpInfo,
  UninstallProcessInfo
);
```

Next, you need to populate the `lpStartupInfo` parameter before using it in the CreateProcess call, as it explains in the documentation for the [STARTUPINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (record, in Pascal-speak), starting with initializing it to empty values and setting the `cb` member to the size of the structure.

```
var
  si: UninstallStartupInfo;
  pi: UninstallProcessInfo;
begin
  FillChar(si, sizeof(si), 0);
  FillChar(pi, sizeof(pi), 0);
  si.cb := sizeof(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  if not CreateProcess(...) then
    // Use GetLastError() here to find out why it failed.
```

Finally, you should also be checking the return value; the [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation tells you what to expect back on success, and what to do if it doesn't return a success code.

(And, just as a note: InnoSetup's Pascal Script has a built in wrapper for executing external files, [ShellExec](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_shellexec), that has a parameter that tells it to wait until the process executes before returning. Using that would make this much easier for you, unless there's a specific reason it won't work for your needs.)

Comment: The FillChar function is not available in Inno Setup.

And when I replace the null with nil it says type mismatch error.

Comment: @Gazben: Ok. Manually fill each member yourself in the code instead. I can't see the code you replaced, so I can't tell you why you're getting a type mismatch error. (I also can't see the way you declared CreateProcess, so I don't know the types it's expecting from your declaration.) I *can* tell you that Pascal does NOT use null, and that doing so will cause the error your original post described.

Comment: I edited the original code above. I filled out every parameter and it worked. Nil nor Null works in this case I don't know why.

Comment: @Gazben, I guess you must have (had) wrong function prototype. Since Inno Setup doesn't support pointers (except `P(Ansi)Char`), I would like to see how did you manage to define all the optional parameters in your prototype. To your code update; you are still not checking the returned values. Any of that function calls may fail which you don't care now running the rest of the code as if nothing happened. That's wrong.

Comment: function prototype:
the {#AW} define deals with the Unicode stuff
`function CreateProcess(
  lpApplicationName : String;
  lpCommandLine : String;
  lpSecurityAttributes : LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
  lpThreadAttributes : LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES;
  bInheritHandles : BOOL;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  var lpEnvironment : LPVOID;
  const lpCurrentDirectory : String;
  lpStartupInfo : LPSTARTUPINFO;
  out lpProcessInformation : LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
  ): BOOL;
external 'CreateProcess{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';`