# Monitor descendant processes creation using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

I'm creating a process (let's say process X) in my program that **may** create child processes, and they **may** do so also, and I'm having trouble determining when the process tree has finished (=all descendants have exited).

I haven't found any direct Boost approach to do so.

**My (non bullet proof) solution** was to maintain a list of monitored processes, starting with only process X in the list, and periodically monitor the processes in the system, and when detecting a process that it's parent id is in the list, add that process id to the list as well. once I get to a monitoring cycle that indicates all processes in the list have finished, then the process tree has finished.

**2 major issues with this approach are:**

1. A process may 'slip' out - consider the following flow:

   - Monitoring cycle has finished and the list is [X].
   - Process X creates a process Y, which creates Z and terminates.
   - Monitoring cycle has started - it won't detect process Y since it
     has finished, and it won't detect process Z because process Y was
     not detected.
2. This type of monitoring is very resource consuming - since it needs to run very frequently in order to minimize these 'slips' described in issue 1.

Some code snippets used in my program:

**Process X creation :**

```
m_process = ps::execute(
                                  boost::process::initializers::set_cmd_line(...),
                                  boost::process::initializers::bind_stdout(sink), // route stdout to a sink/pipe
                                  boost::process::initializers::set_env(...),
                                  boost::process::initializers::start_in_dir(...),
                                  boost::process::initializers::throw_on_error());
```

**Process X monitoring (the simple, insufficient case):**

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
int tmp = ps::wait_for_exit(m_process,timeout,ec);
```

**Important notes:**

1. I have no control over the child process (Process X), nor do I know
   what it is going to do, or what processes will it spawn.
2. My solution should comply for both windows and Linux (if not
   possible, I would have to resort to have OS specific code in my
   program, which was (up until now) agnostic to OS).

Answer (score 1):

If you can alter the child processes to report the PIDs they are creating using some IPC mechanism (stdout, message queueing, shared memory, named pipe...), then you have a start.

You may use Boost Asio with the handles obtained ([`object_handle`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__object_handle.html)).

Otherwise you're likely bound to debugging oriented interfaces (which require elevated permissions), such as

- ptrace on linux (see e.g. `PTRACE_EVENT_VFORK` here http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html)
- Windows: [Waiting for grandchild processes in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683902/waiting-for-grandchild-processes-in-windows/1685864#1685864)

I'd suggest if you control the child processes, you're far better off coordinating the work using IPC

Comment: I have no control over the child process (Process X), nor do I know what it is going to do, or what processes will it spawn. I'll add this important note to the question.

Comment: @Ron.B.I As you can see I have found the relevant answers though. So only on Linux this could prove to be tedious, unless someone else chips in

Comment: Regarding the answers: grandchild processes in our case is just a test case, I'm looking for a general solution, we are talking about an execution software - being able to execute a command line provided by the user, on several Linux flavors and Windows, user can run a script that starts an installation that runs another installation, and stuff like that, Our only knowledge here is the root of the tree, which my process starts. Regarding the ptrace, I'm looking into this but unfortunately as I said, I'm trying to solve it for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Ron.B.I Huh. For the windows variant it's already solved! If you're actually looking to constrain resource usage on Linux, you can use a `chroot + ulimit`; ulimit has features to limit the number of child processes spawned, as well as limit total CPU time consumed by the child + grandchildren (and other things, as largest file creatable, number of open files etc.)

Comment: My main purpose with this is to prevent the next command line being executed until the first one has it's tree finished, given the logic to acquire information about descendant process being spawned (without resource limitation) I can easily monitor and determine that the tree has finished running.

Comment: Right. This means that on windows it's solved using the linked answer ([`AssignProcessToJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx)). On linux, it looks like you should wrap the toplevel fork/exec with a process that uses [`prctl(2)` to set `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/prctl). This means that you can (and should) get signals when any child dies. I _suppose_ this leaves the puzzle of determining when you're truly done and there are no grandchild processes/zombies left (but at least you won't stop early)